# Is a 1h50 connection doable at CDG?

Tags: connecting-flights

I will be traveling from UK to Havana next month and my connection will be 1h50, I´m worried about missing my flight. Is it enough? Thanks!

Comment: Standard answer. Very small risky for a single ticket, very high risk for separate ticket and/or self connection. Depends partially on time of day, your passport/citizenship, checked luggage (or not), status, ticket type etc.

Comment: If you want a more detailed answer, you’ll need to provide quite a few more details, including whether the two flights are on the same ticket or not, whether you have checked luggage, the airline(s) involved and ideally the flights, the date, your citizenship and residence permits or visas… It can range from very likely to work out (single ticket) to completely impossible (separate tickets, checked luggage, different terminals, unfavourable passport…). Note that the answers may also have an effect on possible visa and/or Covid-related requirements.

Comment: The linked question was for Schengen -> International, where this is for International -> International.  The answer still basically stands though - more so in fact given that it's unlikely there will be a need to go through security/immigration (although as per the previous comment, it depends on the exact flight/ticket details).